# magento 2.1.6 in fedora 25 css and js files issues

Tags: javascript, css, magento2.1.6

I have installed **Magento 2.1.6** in Fedora 25, after **successful setup**, but when I run it in the browser, I am getting lots of `css` and `js` files not found errors.

That is loading from **static version folder** which is not even existed. Plus when I tried to access its **admin URL**, it says not found the page.

I have executed its deploy and compile commands as well.

Answer (score 0):

Change or add this setting in the `core_config_data` table:

> scope: default
>   scope_id: 0
>   path: dev/static/sign
>   value: 0

Or execute direct query in database as follows

```
INSERT INTO `core_config_data` (`scope`, `scope_id`, `path`, `value`) VALUES ('default', 0, 'dev/static/sign', '0');
```

This issue is also noted on Github: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7869

Comment: i have done this, but still no success

Comment: Did you deploy static content after this ?

Comment: yes i did. but now once again i run the following commands
#php bin/magento setup:upgrade 
#php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:di:compile 
#php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

But now i tried to access my magento it is blank page now, not showing any error in console

Comment: Ohh its getting 500 Internal Server Error now